# How can I find what query locks the table in postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have many lines in postgres log like this:

```
process 22134 acquired ExclusiveLock on extension of relation 34699881 of database 287114 after 1231.968 ms
```

How can I find the query that cause this locks?

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you can identify the involved relation easily:

```
SELECT 34699881::regclass;
```

Of course, asking in the right database:

```
SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE oid = 287114;
```

To also log statements you could use the setting [`log_statement = ddl`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-STATEMENT). Depending on your setup this might create sizable log output, and not suitable as permanent setting ...